# How to get @Url.Action("actionXXX") to execute that same named action, when there are preceding Actions with HttpPost Attributes on

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, url.action

From my View, using @Url.Action("GetSingleMMCode") in a JQuery-Dialog, when I  open the dialog, the required action does not get hit (executed)
if, ..there is an action before it which is decorated with the [HttpPost], 
.e.g.  see in the controller code beneath, the *Add_MMCode* action

It does hit the Controller and it's Constructor, (I have one as I am using DI..via StructureMap)

If I remove the `[HttpPost]` from the ActionResult *Add_MMCode*, then it is seen/hit/executed.

*(I use the @Url.Action("GetSingleMMCode") in a JQuery Modal dialog (Edit), to return the associated single record to be processed).*

Is this normal?
Is there a way to allow it to work, with all the necessary actions having the 'HttpPost attribute, decorating them?

Thx

Markup.

```
 $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            draggable: false,
            ..
            title: 'Edit MMCode',
            modal: true,
            ..

            open: function (event, ui) {
                // Loads partial view tied to this action

                $(this).load("@Url.Action("GetSingleMMCode")", { id: id });
            }
        });
```

and the Controller

```
public class MMCodeController : Controller
{
    private  readonly IMMCodesService _iService;

    public MMCodeController(IMMCodesService service)
    {
        _iService = new MMCodesService();
        this._iService._UseEF = false;
    }

    public ActionResult MMCode()
    {
       ..
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add_MMCode(string MMCode)
    {
       ..
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetSingleMMCode(int id)
    {
      ..
    }
```

Comment: When you inspect the network, what do you see in the headers? Is it a GET or POST request? Based on load API documentation, if an object is provided it is suppose to do a POST, but it could be doing GET which means GetsingleMMCode would not be executed.

Comment: @Hozikimaru is right, your request is looking for a GET action. How about you change GetSingleMMCode action to GET and if it will work.

Comment: Tried that, but nada, so,..tried this which seems to be working.
[HttpPost, ActionName("GetSingleMMCode")]